# Merging 2 Arrays based on one column

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
a = [[1234,1],[2134,0],[4321,0],[2221,3]]
b = [[2134,1],[4321,3]]
```

I want to merge them based on the first elements of `a` for the following result:

```
c = [[1234,1],[2134,1],[4321,3],[2221,3]]
```

I want to replace 0's in `a` by the value in `b` if the first element match. The first element is unique in a and b.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: it's unclear how you merge them. they should be sorted at least.

Comment: I'm not following the condition of the merge. Are you choosing the one with the largest 2nd element?

Comment: Maybe it's the sum of the second values. But nobody knows, because one of them is always 0 in his example.

Comment: also, what if you have repeatings in first elemtns in b like: b=[[2134,1][4321,3][2134,2]] ?

Comment: All expressions that you gave are not valid Ruby expressions.

Comment: Edited the question to make them valid arrays.

Comment: I reformulated my question, hopefully it is clearer. I specified I want to replace values. The solution  of @tessi does the trick for one case I encountered where I needed to sum the second elements. The Off Topic status astonished me. Several helpful answers have been given based on my description, so it is not so unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Hash#merge` function lets you specify a block to define what to do with the values.

```
a = [[1234,1],[2134,0],[4321,0],[2221,3]]
b = [[2134,1],[4321,3]]
c = Hash[a].merge(Hash[b]) { |key, old, new| old+new }.to_a
# => [[1234, 1], [2134, 1], [4321, 3], [2221, 3]]
```

See the [`Hash#merge` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

In this case I did the merge through building the sum of the values. You might want to choose the largest value, or some other strategy which fits you.

**Disclaimer:** This approach does not work, if `a` (or `b`) contains Arrays having the same first value. Example `[[1, 1], [1, 4], [2, 8]]`. It is not specified in your question if that can happen.

Comment: on target ! Nice @tessi

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
a = [[1234,1],[2134,0],[4321,0],[2221,3]]
```

and

```
b = [[2134,1],[4321,3]]
```

You could transform these arrays into hashes, perform the merge, then transform the result into an array again.

```
Hash[a].merge(Hash[b]).to_a
#=> [[1234, 1], [2134, 1], [4321, 3], [2221, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```
a = [[1234,1],[2134,0],[4321,0],[2221,3]]
b = [[2134,1],[4321,3]]

a.zip(b).flatten(1).uniq(&:first)
# => [[1234, 1], [2134, 1], [4321, 3], [2221, 3]]
```

Comment: Why bother with the zip? Just reverse the arrays: `(b + a).uniq(&:first)`

Comment: True, but it's not clear from the question what exactly needs to be done. I elected to interleave them.

Answer (score 0):

```
[*a, *b].group_by(&:first).map{|k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)]}
```

Comment: I like this approach, I used that today. thanks for sharing @sawa

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the arrays and call unique:

```
(b + a).uniq(&:first)
```

This works because [`Array#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-2B) is a non-mutating version of [`Array#concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat). It'll create a new ordered array. Whichever array is first, will take precedence in the output. When `uniq` is called, it will enumerate over the array in order, allowing you to just get the first instance of the first column.

You can do this for `n` arrays:

```
[b,d,c,a].reduce(&:+).uniq(&:first)
```